# Having a second level submenu flush against main nav

Tags: javascript, html, css

Right now when you hover over Offices > New York, you will notice the nested navigation submenu is flush the "New York" option with some white space above it.

Is there a css way to remove this white space so the nested navigation submenu is flush against the top main nav? Where the "information" option would be right next to "Chicago". The menu that says information, book a meeting, testimonials.

Or does javascript need to get involved

```css
.third-level-menu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -150px;
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}

.third-level-menu > li
{
    height: 30px;
    background: #999999;
}
.third-level-menu > li:hover { background: #CCCCCC; }

.second-level-menu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}

.second-level-menu > li
{
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    background: #999999;
}
.second-level-menu > li:hover { background: #CCCCCC; }

.top-level-menu
{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.top-level-menu > li
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    background: #999999;
}
.top-level-menu > li:hover { background: #CCCCCC; }

.top-level-menu li:hover > ul
{
    /* On hover, display the next level's menu */
    display: inline;
}


/* Menu Link Styles */

.top-level-menu a /* Apply to all links inside the multi-level menu */
{
    font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;

    /* Make the link cover the entire list item-container */
    display: block;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.top-level-menu a:hover { color: #000000; }
```

```html
<ul class="top-level-menu">
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Offices</a>
        <ul class="second-level-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Chicago</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Los Angeles</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">New York</a>
                <ul class="third-level-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Book a Meeting</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Seattle</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: removing the `relative` position from `li` would do the trick, since the children of that would align according to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the position `relative` from the `.second-level-menu li`, it will make the third level reference against the first.

```css
.third-level-menu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -150px;
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}

.third-level-menu > li
{
    height: 30px;
    background: #999999;
}
.third-level-menu > li:hover { background: #CCCCCC; }

.second-level-menu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}

.second-level-menu > li
{
    height: 30px;
    background: #999999;
}
.second-level-menu > li:hover { background: #CCCCCC; }

.top-level-menu
{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.top-level-menu > li
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    background: #999999;
}
.top-level-menu > li:hover { background: #CCCCCC; }

.top-level-menu li:hover > ul
{
    /* On hover, display the next level's menu */
    display: inline;
}


/* Menu Link Styles */

.top-level-menu a /* Apply to all links inside the multi-level menu */
{
    font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;

    /* Make the link cover the entire list item-container */
    display: block;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.top-level-menu a:hover { color: #000000; }
```

```html
<ul class="top-level-menu">
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Offices</a>
        <ul class="second-level-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Chicago</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Los Angeles</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">New York</a>
                <ul class="third-level-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Book a Meeting</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Seattle</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `display : relative` in `.second-level-menu > li` with something else. There are multiple other display types that can do what you would like.

Comment: Try looking at [W3 Schools CSS Display page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) to find alternative options

Comment: Also if you have not figured it out here is a codepen with it being fixed by using block https://codepen.io/Bracciata/pen/WLGvgY